# Where does the "type.less" come from and why does it overwrite some of my styles?

Tags: c#, css, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap-3, asp.net-mvc-5

In my *simple* MVC application with only one page `/Home/Index` (for now) I noticed that some of my styles are being overwritten by a *mysterious* `type.less`:

[image: type.less screenshot]

Chrome says the file would come from

```
http://localhost:123/Content/less/type.less
```

but I couldn't find anything there.

The `css` files are also included in the right order so the `main.css` shouldn't actually be overriden:

[image: css load order]

The history of my actions:

I created a new `MVC` project in `Visual Studio 2013` and I updated all references with the nugget-manager.

Then I and changed the following files:

(I list only changes related to `css` but I also added `knockout` and a few custom `*.js` files written by me)

**`BundleConfig.cs`** where I added `jquery-ui.min.css`:

```
bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/css").Include(
          "~/Content/bootstrap.css",
          "~/Content/site.css",
          "~/Content/jquery-ui.min.css"));
```

and my `main.css`

```
bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/Custom").Include(
          "~/Content/Custom/main.css"
));
```

**`_Layout.cshtml`** to render my new bundle and excluded the `modernizr` because I thought I might be the reason (it didn't help):

```
@Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
@Styles.Render("~/Content/Custom")
@*@Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/modernizr")*@
```

then I excluded another three lines there to make the `tyle.less` go away (but it didn't work either):

```
<body>    
    <div class="container center">
        @RenderBody()        
    </div>

    @*@Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/jquery")
    @Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/bootstrap")
    @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)*@
</body>
```

`Index.cshtml` contains only the title and `html`

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Lorem ipsum";
}
```

apart of this I didn't change anything else.

I was able to find a *reference* to the `type.less` only in the `bootstrap.css.map` file which is apparently minified and a long line of different styles but the file `type.less` physically doesn't seem to exist anywhere. I don't understand why it wants to override my css. Do you know what might cause this and how to *disable* it or load it *before* my `css` so that it doesn't distroy anything?

Comment: No `type.less` file in the solution anywhere?

Comment: ...oh wait, there is one file that contains the string `type.less` in the `bootstrap.css.map` (which seems to be minimized and is only a single long line of styles. - I've updated my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out that some strange [bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/) that is installed

> by default in new MVC5 projects

*[Bootstrap for ASP.NET MVC](http://responsivemvc.azurewebsites.net/Bootstrap)*

caused all that trouble. Because I wasn't able to find how to prevent it from overwriting my styles I decided to uninstall it and finally I have my styles back.